# Using ajax to refresh a div content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

I'm using JavaScript to handle my form submission and an Ajax call to refresh a certain div only **"not the entire page"**, the form submission is successful but the value inside of the div doesn't refresh. I've tried other methods/solutions on stack overflow but they all seem to load the entire page or the content of the div is hidden on form submission.

**ajax.js**

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
      $('.ajaxform').submit(function (e) {
          e.preventDefault(); // catch the form's submit event
          $.ajax({ // create an AJAX call...
              data: $(this).serialize(), // get the form data
              type: "POST", // POST
              dataType: 'html',
              url: "info.php", // the file to call
              cache: false,
              success: function (response) { // on success..
                  $(".ld").load("info.php .ld"); //this hides the content of the div
                  // $('.ld').html(response);----This loads the entire page inside the div
              }
          });
          return false; // cancel original event to prevent form submitting
      });
  });
```

**info.php**

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
    <?php
        ...................
        foreach($stmt as $obj){
            $id = $obj['id'];
            $likes = $obj['like1'];

            echo '<form action="" method="post" id="ajaxform" enctype="multipart/form-data">';
            echo '<input type="hidden" name="lkcv[]" value="'.$id.'">';
            echo '<input type="hidden" name="like" value="">';
            echo '<input type="image" src="images/like.png" id="lksub" width="15" 
                 value="som" height="15" style="float:right;position:relative;
                 margin-right:290px;"/><div class="ld">'.$likes.'</div>';
            echo '</form>’;
            echo '<div id="emailform"></div>';
        }
    ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

i am trying to refresh the variable "$likes" inside the div tag, without refreshing the whole page, right now my current code hides the variable on form submit. i have to refresh manually to view any changes to "$likes".

Comment: Ids have to be unqiue

Comment: @ Andreas, i'm using classes in my forms and the divs i want to refresh.

Comment: you want  info.php in your div or only generated html within it?

Comment: In the posted `foreach` loop are three ids which would result in duplicated ids if there is more than one element in `$obj`

Comment: You are sending your XMLHTTPRequest to a whole document and not to a portion of PHP (That's what you need as I understand your question). Additionnaly, you are sending the request to the same current page, better separate the concerns by splitting your PHP code to two parts (the one the renders the intial form and the one that is inteneded to be returned when form processed)

Comment: You should have a dedicated PHP file for the Ajax-call, which does the update and returns a JSON object (use `dataType: 'json'`). Then you can update the HTML just as you liked with JavaScript by getting `response.likes` or something like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are sending an XMLHTTPRequest to a whole document and not to a portion of PHP (It is the latter that you need as I understand from your question). Additionnaly, you are sending the request to the same current page `info.php`, it is better  to separate the concerns by splitting your PHP code to two parts (the one the renders the intial form and the one that is intentended to process it server side).

As a result, the AJAX will return all result of `info.php` (static markup + generated markup) and return all the final HTML and load it in `.ld`.

What I suggest is to create two files: `form.php` and `process-form.php`.Your AJAX call will be performed when document returened by `form.php` is `ready` and will be sent to `process-form` which will return required data after form processed.

And this should work without refreshing the page (the main purpose of using AJAX).